# To use Myriad pro on website, but light or other?

Tags: fonts, typefaces, sans-serif

Sorry for my english and for my question.. (I don't know more about font)

I would like to change the font on my website. I like "san francisco font" but is impossible to use it.
Other option is MYRIAD PRO..
i like light version but i dont' know which are difference between only "Myriad pro", light and extra light..

And i don't know the better option for my website (where there are pages with long article)..

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to use Myriad Pro on your website or looking for advice on which would be the best weight to use?

If the former, you will need to either own a license for web-use of the typeface or use a webfont service. Adobe [Typekit includes Myriad Pro](https://typekit.com/fonts/myriad-pro). If you have a Creative Cloud package you may have access to Typekit and therefor can use it from there. They have clear instructions on the different ways of using webfonts.

If you're simply asking which weight is best to use on your site, then I'd have to say that depends on the design of the site, coupled with the amount of text (you mention there are long articles) and also personal preference. With the numerous different variants in screen resolutions you need to choose a typeface which is legible across all screens – last thing you want is a user not being able to read your article. Sometimes if a typeface is too light it can make it difficult to read.

Going back to Typekit, you can try out the different weights live on their site to get an idea of which variant you prefer. You also need to be careful with how many weights you decide to use. If you add bold, regular and light, for example, you're adding more bytes to your pages which will have an impact on load times. I tend to stick to two or three webfonts per site which may include a headline typeface and body, both regular & bold, or similar such as semi-bold and light.

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: I found a free  alternative to "myriad pro" and found "PT Sans" between fonts google ... I did a test on a piece of text from one of my web page between "PT Sans" and the current font "Georgia "...

PT Sans looks better but Georgia is perhaps more readable? what do you think about it?

both have a font-size of 15px     see http://i60.tinypic.com/24dqaux.png

Answer (score 0):

For a website with articles (long articles as you mentioned). Using pretty much ANY font as extra-light (weight 100 or 200 , depending on the font) will leave your readers in tears (and believe me, not of joy) and agony after reading just one article. Since it's an article, your font-size will not go over 16 and it will be incredibly hard to read.

Even Light isn't the best way to go...for long articles, regular weight fonts are best for the eyes (that being about 300 font-weight) but if you have to choose between Light and Extra Light...go with Light.